# Extract a vector with dplyr while maintaining ID variable for each row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data set:

```
df<-structure(list(spp = list(c("Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)", 
"Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)"), 
    c("Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)", "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)", 
    "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)"
    ), c("Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)", "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)"
    )), ID = c("1", "2", "3")), row.names = 3:5, class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to turn the `spp` column into a vector of species that are separated by a comma but maintain the survey ID. I know I can do it with this code:

```
unlist(strsplit(df$Q7, ","))
```

But how can I manipulate this data frame so that it looks like this, maintaining the ID column:

```
> harv
                                                       spp ID
1    Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)  1
2 Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)  1
3                         Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)  2
4    Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)  2
5 Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)  2
6                         Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)  3
7    Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)  3
```

I'd prefer to do this in dplyr, but any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
df |> 
  rename(Q7_1_TEXT = Q7) |> 
  rename_with(~gsub("_TEXT$", "", .x), ends_with("TEXT")) |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c(".value", "name"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  filter(!is.na(Q8)) |> 
  select(ID, spp = Q7, num = Q8)
```

the code here gets what I was after.